# TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() error while sending value from excel to web element text box using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, sendkeys

Code trials:

```
sheet = inputbook.sheet_by_name('Page1')
for x in range(rowcount) : 
    #formname = driver.find_element_by_id('walletRequest') 
    #formname.click() value1 = sheet.cell_value(x,0) str(value1) 
    #time.sleep(10) 
    aname = driver.find_element_by_id('accountName').send_keys(sheet.cell_value(x,0)) 
    aname.click() 
    aname.clear() 
    time.sleep(1) 
    #aname.keys(value1) 
    #aname.send_keys(value1) 
    time.sleep(3)
```

Error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-5e4cc31778ca> in <module>
     45     str(value1)
     46     #time.sleep(10)
---> 47     aname = driver.find_element_by_id('accountName').send_keys(sheet.cell_value(x,0))
     48     aname.click()
     49     aname.clear()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
    476 
    477         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
--> 478                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
    479                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    480 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py in keys_to_typing(value)
    148                 typing.append(val[i])
    149         else:
--> 150             for i in range(len(val)):
    151                 typing.append(val[i])
    152     return typing

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Comment: sheet = inputbook.sheet_by_name('Page1')for x in range(rowcount) :
    #formname = driver.find_element_by_id('walletRequest')
    #formname.click()
    value1 = sheet.cell_value(x,0)
    str(value1)
    #time.sleep(10)
    aname = driver.find_element_by_id('accountName').send_keys(sheet.cell_value(x,0))
    aname.click()
    aname.clear()
    time.sleep(1)
    #aname.keys(value1)  
    #aname.send_keys(value1)
    time.sleep(3)

Comment: Please add your code in question, not in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

...implies that you have tried to send a **float** value through `send_keys()` in the line:

```
aname = driver.find_element_by_id('accountName').send_keys(sheet.cell_value(x,0))
```

Where as `send_keys()` can only *strings* (*text*).

---

### Solution

You need to convert the **float** value into **string** to be able to invoke through `send_keys()` as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('accountName').send_keys(str(sheet.cell_value(x,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. can you tell me how i can pass int value to web element textbox

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. can you tell me how i can pass int value to web element textbox

Comment: @mayurkhairnar `send_keys()` will only send _character sequence_ and you need to ensure that non string _character sequence_ is converted into _strings_ before invoking through `send_keys()`. Element attributes/field will validate whether the given input is in desired format e.g. `string`, `int`, `float` or not.